# Include Java cartridge in Virtuoso Sponger

Tags: java, virtuoso

I have one question. I wrote a program in Java that is extracting data from one website and returning me in RDF (turtle type) format, for example (output with `System.out.println()`):

```
@prefix dutb: <http://dutb.eu/si/o-nas/informacije-javnega-znacaja/informacije-javnega-znacaja-povezane-s-krediti-podjetij-prenesenih-na-dutb-s-strani-nlb-d-d/> .

_:1ede2231-81f7-46a0-9637-8b5efc3d5b42 dutb:firma "A.K.S. V STEČAJU" .
_:1ede2231-81f7-46a0-9637-8b5efc3d5b42 dutb:sedezNaslov "TRG OF 8" .
_:1ede2231-81f7-46a0-9637-8b5efc3d5b42 dutb:sedezKraj "LJUBLJANA" .
_:1ede2231-81f7-46a0-9637-8b5efc3d5b42 dutb:brutoIzpostavljenostEUR 10276742.43 .

_:5d5bc4ae-1d83-44fe-aac2-ce5700128eb9 dutb:firma "ABA PLUS D.O.O." .
_:5d5bc4ae-1d83-44fe-aac2-ce5700128eb9 dutb:sedezNaslov "KERSNIKOVA CESTA 6" .
_:5d5bc4ae-1d83-44fe-aac2-ce5700128eb9 dutb:sedezKraj "LJUBLJANA" .
_:5d5bc4ae-1d83-44fe-aac2-ce5700128eb9 dutb:brutoIzpostavljenostEUR 14744517.27 .

...
```

The syntax is correct, because I checked it in Protege program. I read this tutorial through:
http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/virtuososponger.html, but here i haven't seen how to use this cartridge in Virtuoso Sponger, where to upload .java file, I just registered cartridge, but where is no option to upload a .java file or whatever to use it.

If anyone already developed a custom Java cartridge for Virtuoso sponger, please give me link how did you include it in VS or write me how did you included it in VS. Thank you very much!